# What is the fourier transform of $xf'(x)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of $xf'(x)$? I have tried using integration by parts, and I only end up with a long messy equation that gives no results.

Comment: You might find useful the [convolution theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html).

Comment: In the context of Fourier transforms **$\ast$ is the convolution**

Answer (score 4):

Use [properties of Fourier transform](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html):
assuming $$\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}=F(w),$$

> $$\mathcal{F}\{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\}=jwF(w)$$
> $$\mathcal{F}\{-jxg(x)\}=\frac{d}{dw}G(w)$$

where $g(x)=f'(x)$ in here.
Therefore,
$$\mathcal{F}\{xf'(x)\}=j\frac{d}{dw}\left(jwF(w)\right)=-(F(w)+w\frac{d}{dw}F(w))$$